# Lighttpd and PHP generates error "No input file specified" after server.document-root is moved

Tags: php, configuration, lighttpd

I would like to use Lighttpd and PHP to provide a lightweight standalone web server on Windows.  I downloaded all the latest builds yesterday and after an hour everything was working fine.

Today, I changed **server.document-root** from **server_root + "/htdocs"** to **server_root + "/../htdocs"** and adjusted my directory structure accordingly.  After restarting everything, I see "No input file specified" in the web browser when I try to access php pages.

Here are my configuration files.  Of course, I've tried playing with **cgi.fix_pathinfo** and **fastcgi.server** but I can't seem to find the correct settings.  Any ideas?

**php.ini**

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

extension_dir = .\ext
extension = php_pdo_sqlite.dll 

date.timezone = UTC

log_errors = On
error_log = ..\logs\php_error.log
```

**lighttpd.conf**

```
## modules to load
# at least mod_access and mod_accesslog should be loaded
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_accesslog",
    "mod_fastcgi",
#   "mod_cgi",
    "mod_status"
)

#### include important configuration files
include "variables.conf"
include "mimetype.conf"

## a static document-root
## works fine
server.document-root        = server_root + "/htdocs"
## causes "No input file specified"
#server.document-root        = server_root + "/../htdocs"

# extensions that should not be handle via static-file transfer
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php" )

## virtual directory listings
dir-listing.activate        = "disable"

#directory for file uploads
server.upload-dirs          = ( temp_dir )

# files to check for if .../ is requested
index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html" )

## set the event-handler (read the performance section in the manual)
server.event-handler        = "libev"

## deny access the file-extensions
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc", ".htaccess" )

## disable range request for PDF files
$HTTP["url"] =~ "\.pdf$" {
  server.range-requests = "disable"
}

#### status module
status.status-url           = "/server-status"
status.config-url           = "/server-config"

#### fastcgi module
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ("localhost" => ("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 521, "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable" )))
#cgi.assign = ( ".php" => "C:/development/tds/PHP/php-cgi.exe" )
```

**this directory structure works**

```
c:\base_dir
    \php
    \lightTPD
       \htdocs
```

**this is the directory structure I'm trying to achieve**

```
c:\base_dir
     \htdocs
     \php
     \lightTPD
```

Comment: Have you check [this part](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/frequentlyaskedquestions#I-get-the-error-No-input-file-specified-when-trying-to-use-PHP) of the doc?

Comment: Yes.  That's why I was playing with cgi.fix_pathinfo and fastcgi.server.  Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Have you tried to put the absolute path to htdocs instead of the relative one (with `/../` inside)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I don't want to use absolute paths.  I'm using a workaround for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a workaround for now.

```
mklink /J htdocs ..\htdocs
```

If anyone has a better solution I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

check your doc_root is set right in php.ini

```
doc_root = C:\base_dir\htdocs
```

thats all mine needed

if you don't want an absolute path, you can unset it and it should also work.

```
; doc_root = ""
```

just tried it on mine with no issues